# List of currently loaded node.js modules?

Tags: node.js

Is there a function in node.js that gives me all currently loaded modules - or even better, their filenames?

I want to restart my process as soon as a loaded module gets updated and so need to know which files need to be monitored for changes...

Comment: Why not use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)?

Comment: Because it monitors all kinds of files, not just effectively loaded modules. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check the `module` module source. Your answer is:

```
Object.keys(require('module')._cache);
```

Comment: This code prints list of currently loaded node modules (filenames).

Comment: it does not include the user defined modules?

Answer (score 15):

To complement [Anatoliy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794268/45375):

Since Node.js v0.3.0, [`require.cache`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) contains the loaded non-core modules:

```
 Object.keys(require.cache);  # lists full filenames of loaded non-core modules
```

The advantage of `require.cache` is that it is *documented*, unlike `module._cache`.

Note:

- Core modules such as `util` do NOT show up in `require.cache`.

  - To test if a module is a core module, use `require.resolve(<name>)`: if it returns `<name>`, i.e., merely the module *name* itself, the module is core; non-core modules will return their full filename.
- `require.cache` contains a hash of all currently loaded non-core modules as [`module`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) instances, keyed by their full filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example if you want to filter on a specific lib / module name :

```
const libs = Object.keys(require('module')._cache);

const filteredItems = libs.filter(item => {
   return item.includes('aLibName');
});

console.log(filteredItems);
```