# Node.js - searching for the "util" module; identify core modules

Tags: node.js, reflection, module, require

I'm really a big fan of Swagger's node [module](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node), but one thing is driving me crazy:

The sample app contains the following line (`api/controller/hello_world.js`):

```
var util = require('util');
```

But I just *can't* find this module. I tried to

- list it with `npm list` but nothing
- search for it with Spotlight (`util.js`)

My question is: How can I list the actually loaded modules in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TimWolla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832570/45375) solves your *particular* problem with respect to the `util` module.

As for the more *generic* question:

> How can I list the actually loaded modules in nodejs?

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833257/45375) tells you how to **list the full filenames of currently loaded *non-core* modules** (spoiler alert: `Object.keys(require.cache)`.
- For *core* modules - modules that come with Node.js itself, such as `util` - there is no way that I know of that tells you which ones are loaded, but given that they're *core*, they may all *implicitly* be loaded, for all we know (and should care).
- That said, to **test if a given module is a *core* module**, you can use [`require.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve), which returns the input module name as-is (rather than a full filename) in the case of core modules; e.g.:

  ```
  require.resolve('util') // -> 'util', i.e. NOT A PATH -> core module
  ```

Note: When `require.resolve()` returns a filesystem path, the implication is merely that the module is *non-core* and can be *located*; it does *not* tell you whether or not that module is currently *loaded* (use `require.cache` for that).

Answer (score 2):

`util` is part of the node.js distribution: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html

Comment: thank you, but mklement0's answer is general. thanks anyway.