# Is it possible to list all identifiers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

In Python, one can use dir() to list the names of all modules and variables that are accessible at any point in the code. I wonder whether the same is possible in JavaScript.

I tried `Object.keys(require('module')._cache);` to see the modules, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791925/list-of-currently-loaded-node-js-modules), but I get 'require is not defined'.

Comment: The question you are refering to is about Node.js. And Node.js != Browser. Therefore `require` is not available to you.